# Android BitmapDecode in listview

Tags: android, string, listview, bitmap

I use the folowing to get a bitmap from my device and display it in a listview

```
pic1="Harris1.jpg"
pic2="Harris2.jpg"
pic3="Harris3.jpg"

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/" + pic1);
Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/" + pic2);
Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/" + pic3);
Bitmap[] image={bmp,bmp1,bmp2};

        for(int i=0;i<text1.length;i++)
        {
        item_details.setImage(image[i]);
        }
```

this works fine but is there a way to buildup the Bitmap {} image without having to put a line for each = BitmapFactory.decodeFile?

I want to be able to read the filenames from a database which I can do but sometimes there are just 3 pictures but other times here may by 50 and I want to be able for the routine to do the {bmp,bmp1,bmp2 etc...} automatically

Any ideas?

Your help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code sample. Using the `String.format` method is the simplest way to achieve your goal.

```
String picFormat="Harris%d.jpg";
for(int i=0;i<text1.length;i++)
{
    String pic = String.format(picFormat, i+1);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/" + pic);
    item_details.setImage(bmp);
}
```